# Creating generic routing for add and delete in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, routes, asp.net-mvc-4

As you cant use Put and Delete on most hosted sites I am trying to create a route that avoids using these, but I cant get that to work..

I want a route like this

```
api/someController/Add/someInt
```

with this RESTsharp code

```
private RestClient client;

public RESTful()
    {
        client = new RestClient
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
            BaseUrl = "http://localhost:6564/api/",
            //BaseUrl = "http://localhost:21688/api/",
            //BaseUrl = "http://madsskipper.dk/api/"
        };
    }

    public void AddFriend(int userId)
    {
        client.Authenticator = GetAuth();

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
            Resource = "Friends/Add/{userId}"
        };

        request.AddParameter("userId", userId);

        client.PostAsync(request, (response, ds) =>
        {
        });
    }
```

To hit this method in my FriendsController

```
// POST /api/friends/add/Id
[HttpPost] //Is this necesary?
public void Add(int id)
{         
}
```

So I have added this in my route config

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiAdd",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/Add/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But when I do this I only hit my FriensController's Constructor and not the Add Method

EDIT:

Also tried making this route config

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiAdd",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Add", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

But same result, the controller is hit but not the action

---

Solution:
Found out the parameters was added wrongly with RESTsharp, so instead of

```
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
    {
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
        Resource = "Friends/Add/{userId}"
    };

    request.AddParameter("userId", userId);
```

It should be

```
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
            Resource = "Friends/Add/{userId}"
        };

        request.AddUrlSegment("userId", userId.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include the action name in your Api route definition:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and then have this action:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Add(int id)
{

}
```

Now you could trigger a POST request to the `/api/friends/add/123` url.

The `[HttpPost]` attribute ensures that this action can only be invoked using the POST verb. If you remove it you could still invoke it through GET, but that's something you shouldn't do with actions that potentially modify state on the server.

Comment: That makes sense, but I tried it like this http://pastebin.com/A9nNqq26 and it aint working, it still only hits the FriendsController constructor, I have this other method that calls the Get() on the same controller that works just fine http://pastebin.com/XcuHzE0i